# GNU Screen: Changing Global Key-binding

Tags: emacs, gnu-screen

I've recently started using screen in remote sessions.  One problem is that emacs doesn't recognize its C-a and I don't want to bind emacs C-a to something else, as I'm very used to it.

Google shows ways to change every keybinding individually using ~/.screenrc  but not how to change a keybinding globally.  I want all C-a to change to something else.  Is that possible?  What are my options?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can change the escape combination via `escape` in `.screenrc`:

```
# Makes Control+b become the escape combination
escape ^Bb
```

You can also just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> to pass a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> to the child process. You get used to it after a while.

Comment: I use Z as the control character. It is easy to type and just replaces the ability to background processes with one keystroke (which I use infrequently).

Comment: I have set the control character to O.  Convenient and doesn't interfere with regular apps.  Since I have to do a lot of my stuff on different boxes,  I should try not to get used to non-standard shortcuts for standard apps. :(